# React & require: Error: Cannot find module "."

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, require

I have a fairly simple stateless component

```
const Image = ({
    uri,
}) => {
    function getImage(uri) {
        return require(uri);
    }

    return (
        <img
            className='image'
            src={getImage(uri)} />
    )
}

export default Image;
```

That gives me

> Error: Cannot find module "."
>   webpackMissingModule

The image is in the `assets` folder of my app.

I also tried

```
<img
    lassName='image'
    src={require(uri)} />
```

The path looks like `'../../assets/someImage.jpg'`

Why cant I use `require` with a variable name? When I hardcode the path it works... The path I am giving cannot be wrong because if using the wrong path I would get something like

> ... not found: Can't resolve ....

Comment: src={require(uri)} can you check is this works for you

Comment: Use src={require(`pathvariable`)} in react you need to import image but if you are using it without import then use inline require

Comment: @Stophface whats the uri variable gives , i tried with this its working for me. <img src={require('./logo.svg')}></img>

Comment: @Stophface It should be, `require('path/to/file.js' )`

Comment: @Stophface can you just post your folder structure where the image is located and which component you are calling the image , may be a small issue with the proper reference of path. So i can update the answer

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS If it would be a reference error, the error would be different. Something like `... not found: Can't resolve ....`

Comment: @Stophface yeah may be but its best to check the path was it referring proper. like i understood you have src folder where you have src/assets/images/img.png and the component that you are loading is from src/components/ImageComponent/ImageComponent.js

Comment: @Stophface so i hope it got resolved

Comment: @Stophface can you just check the answer i have updated it :) please let me know whether it worked for you

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS Doesnt work.

Comment: @Stophface same error ??

Comment: @Stophface why are you not posting the detailed error ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `require()` itself. `require()` get's fired, when the app starts. When a path is passed statically, `require()` knows where to look when the app starts and all is good. However, when the path gets passed dynamically, `require()`  does not know on start up of the app where to look for the image. Hence, it does not find it. That is why `requiere()` cannot take a dynamically created path.

Use `src=''` relative from your `index.html` or your `public` folder (depends on your configuration).

Answer (score -1):

**if its a url**

```
 <img src={'https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1600/1*DsD06sTC-X5AVj_m9nElRg.jpeg'}></img>
```

**or you can store the url in a variable and use in the src like**

```
var url = 'https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1600/1*DsD06sTC-X5AVj_m9nElRg.jpeg';
        <img src={url}></img>
```

**if its a file inside the src folder**

```
<img src={require('./logo.svg')}></img>
```

**in your case- Solution**

```
 getImage = (url) => {
     return require(`${url}`)
   }

  <img src={this.getImage(url)}></img>
```

Comment: In require you need to pass it as a string you can concatenate or in es6 you can use template literals.

Answer (score -1):

Two things I noticed in your code.

When you want to add css styles to jsx elements you need to use className but lassName. Not sure if it is a typo error :)

When you want to import images and add the path to src.

Do some thing like below and make sure your image path is correct.

```
import uri from '../../assets/someImage.jpg';
<img
className='image'
src={uri} />
```